# Javascript - Regular Expression For two uppercase, lowercase and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expression.

I have written one for uppercase, lowercase, 10 characters (min) and a number.

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])\S{10,}$/g
```

This validates correctly.

I was wondering if I could run a check for a minimum of two uppercase chars, two lowercase chars and two numbers?

I have tried:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})\S{10,}$/g
```

Cheers

Comment: take out the `^` and the `$` and it should be fine: http://regex101.com/r/aS5iC1/1

Comment: Why so much look aheads? If you want to find a sequence of one uppercase, one lowercase, >= 10 any, and a digit, the natural pattern would be `/[A-Z][a-z]\S{10,}\d/` ? Did I miss some point in the question? The second pattern would be `/[A-Z]{2,}[a-z]{2,}\d{2,}/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's easy, you only need to repeat twice the **whole** content of each lookahead *(using a non-capturing group)*:

```
/^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2})\S{10,}$/
```

You can improve the pattern using negated character classes:

```
/^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})\S{10,}$/
```

Note: since you test all the string with a single pattern anchored at the begining and at the end, you don't need to add "g" for a global research.

Comment: This was a perfect answer. Solved.